# JavaFX Chart Series ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, javafx, task

I'm building a genetic algorithm on JavaFX and I want to have a chart that will update the average and the maximum fitness of every generation. 
I have A button, that does 20 generations, updates the graph every iteration and also the progress bar.

The code used to be simplier, without all those duplicares and references. These are just the ideas on how to avoid the exception. But nothing worked

I mean, I don't even iterate or delete something. This is just about adding.

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
    at javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart.layoutPlotChildren(AreaChart.java:451)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:731)
    at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Chart.java:94)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1079)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$31(Toolkit.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:347)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:374)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$405(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Here is the preparation**

```
public void prepareChart() {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final AreaChart<Number, Number> graph = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
    graph.setCreateSymbols(false);
    graph.setTitle("Fitness - Generations relation");
    graph.getXAxis().setLabel("Generations");
    graph.getYAxis().setLabel("Fitness");

    final Series<Number, Number> averageFitness = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
    averageFitness.setName("Average fitness");

    final Series<Number, Number> maximumFitness = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
    maximumFitness.setName("Maximum fitness");
    graph.getData().addAll(averageFitness, maximumFitness);
    graphBox.getChildren().add(graph);
    graphRef = graph;
}
```

**Here is how I add data**

```
public void addData(double avgFitness, double maxFitness) {
    final Series<Number, Number> averageFitness = graphRef.getData().get(0);
    final Series<Number, Number> maximumFitness = graphRef.getData().get(1);
    averageFitness.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(generation, avgFitness));
    maximumFitness.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(generation, maxFitness));
    generation++;

}
```

**Here is what happens when the button is clicked**

```
public void twentyGenerationsPressed() {

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            disableButtons();
            solver.nextGeneration();
            updateProgress(i, 20);
            executor.execute(() -> {
            addData(solver.getAverage(), solver.getCurrentBest().getFitness());
            });

        }

        return null;
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        updateLabels();
        enableButtons();
    });

    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();

}
```

Comment: You're calling `addData(...)` in a task, which means the method is not invoked on the `FX Thread`, but on a different `Thread`. Try to move the code, which updates the UI to `task.setOnSucceeded`, e.g.

Comment: But this will update the UI only one time. I have 20 iterations and I want a live update for each one

Comment: Why are you using concurrency and a task?  Does something about the process take a lot of time?  If so, how much time for each iteration and the total process and what is the method which takes the time and why does it take time, is it doing a lot of complex calculations and consuming CPU or it is waiting on I/O or it artificially paused via a thread sleep call?  The answers to these questions should help you choose between a task or timeline based approach.

Comment: Okay, so the method .nextGeneration() doesn't actually run momentally, but I though I don't need to pause the thread for this to work.

Comment: And I have no idea how much should I wait for the method to finish. It depends on the size of the input...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, anytime you modify the contents of JavaFX objects, it should be performed on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Replace this:

```
executor.execute(() -> {
    addData(solver.getAverage(), solver.getCurrentBest().getFitness());
});
```

With this:

```
final double avg = solver.getAverage();
final double best = solver.getCurrentBest().getFitness();
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        addData(avg, best);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said and this returns completly strange results. The maximum fitness may even go below the average one.
By the way, running the update out of the runLater gives nice results, but always fails somewhere at generation 60 - 200

Comment: I have added in the runLater a System.out.println of the results that I add to the graph. Seems like they are not even close to what the graph shows

Comment: Try putting the whole for loop in the platform.runlater call.  The results you notice are likely from the task updating data you're consuming while the JavaFX Application Thread to wait to get flagged.

Comment: Putting the whole loop in the runLater (with the condition that the rest of the code remains intact) updates only when the for finishes it's iterations (only at the last iteration)
Maybe I should get rid of the task and run only runLater?

Comment: And also the whole window freezes while the function is in progress

Comment: Yeah, that is expected.  Basically, Whenever you're running operations on the JavaFX Application Thread, that thread is not processing GUI requests, so it seems frozen.  Running the "for" loop on the JavaFX thread is not a permanent solution; I was just curious if you noticed results that were more in-line with expectations.  You need to access JavaFX operations on the JavaFX Application Thread, but you also don't want to spend much computational time that isn't related to JavaFX on that thread (because of the prior).

Comment: What is the solution then?

Comment: So to summarize, you have two things conflicting right now: addData() is trying to consume data stored in graphRef, and I'm guessing that same graphRef object is being modified by other portions of the for loop.  You need to prevent that.

Comment: The for loop is actually the only place from where addData gets called. And no, the graphRef is not modified by anything else

Comment: It's not about addData().  I'm more concerned with the graphRef object, and where else it is being modified (if it is?).  It's hard to provide great feedback with just code fragments to work off of, which is why it is normally requested to attach an SCCEE/MCVE instead.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No, it is not. It is only created and the only modified by addData().
And to provide a MCVE, I need to paste here a few classes that are quite complex and long

Comment: Alright, well, another potential issue is accessing the solver.  If you access the solver.getAverage() and solver.getCurrentBest() calls within a runLater, then the JavaFX thread might end up accessing the solver when it's in an inconsistent state.

Comment: I have tested it a few times and looks like it's working. I'll keep checking, but thank you for helping, I was really stuck on this question

Comment: No problem, glad it's working.  If, after testing, you're comfortable saying that the problem is fixed, I'd appreciate it if you could mark this as the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the graph in a `Timeline` animation.

```
   Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
   timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), evt -> addData(...)));
   timeline.setCycleCount(20);

   button.setOnAction(e -> timeline.play());
```

The timeline has the benefit, that you can specify the duration between the updates, which I can not see in your code

Comment: The update (even with Duration of 1 ms) is not smooth at all. How do I make it smooth?